# how to create view that expand & shrink on click?

Tags: android

I have to display list of items along with a plus(+) sign , on click of plus sign list should expand & on click again list should shrink

Comment: Yes exactly. You have to use custom Adapter for an ExpandableListView. Start with understanding how they work, do some research using Examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but would need to do more work
as you want to show

name ,address and plus sign should changed to minus ,
you would require to make a custom list view and what you can do is use

when plus button is clicked in list

```
 nameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                

adress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.minus);
```

and when minus button is clicked

```
nameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

adress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a tree view like windows, then it is not a UI element that is supported by android. The similar to this is the `ExplandableListView` element.

Although in one business application I have found this http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/ project that does exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks for reply but that code is quite difficult to understand am new to android

Comment: i think have to make use of animation class but don't know exact process

Comment: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2008/05/expandable-lists.html see this link might help you

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/ and this

Comment: You don't have to implement anything. Just include the library I provided and follow some examples. If you are new to android, perhaps you should at first understand how to implement components that involve adapters in android and then do something advanced, because either `ExpandableListView` or this library is quite difficult for someone that has just started to understand and implement.

Comment: @10s it fine. but my need is user can able to open single link suppose the user try to click other one the previous one should shrink. how to do this??

Comment: @AristoMichael you should programmatically close all other list items. There is a method in the library that uncollapses all the list items. I don't remember the name.